# Firebase iOS Push Notifications Delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification

I am working on Push Notifications for the first time. I am using Firebase for this purpose. 
I am only dealing with PushNotification when app is in active state for now. Without firebase, the delegate methods called for handling incoming notification and its tapping are as follows (iOS 10):

```
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    // Print message ID.
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler();
}
```

Now, coming to Firebase, I 've the following method to show the incoming message.

```
- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage  {

    NSLog(@"%@", remoteMessage.appData);
    [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:[remoteMessage.appData objectForKey:@"message_title"]
                                subtitle:[remoteMessage.appData objectForKey:@"message_body"]
                                    type:TSMessageNotificationTypeMessage];
}
```

**Issues:**
1) Above Firebase method has not got a completion handler to use completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);

2) How do I handle tap on Notification in case of Firebase?

Comment: In the given sample code, I could understand that you are showing an alert when you receive a notification. Why don't you perform your action when user interact with this alert?

Comment: That's a third party library. I want to avoid using it. Also, for iOS 10, apple has given the option to use completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert) but I am not sure how to use it with firebase.

Comment: - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler                Is this method getting called when you receive a notification?

Comment: Are you sending Data message or Notification Message?

Comment: @chengsam..Data message it is!